# Multiple lines in an If statement

Tags: conditional

What I am wondering is how do you perform multiple lines when using the If statement. I know the following is not proper Mathematica code, but how would I do this in Mathematica?

```
if(x<1,
 y=2x;
 z=2y
else
 y=x/2;
 z=y/2
)
```

**Mr. Wizard help:**

It does work. For example:

```
In[181]:= x = 0; If[x < 1, y = 2 x; z = 2 y, y = x/2; z = y/2]

Out[181]= 0
```

Another example:

```
In[182]:= x = 2; If[x < 1, y = 2 x; z = 2 y, y = x/2; z = y/2]

Out[182]= 1/2
```

But if the expressions are quite long and complicated, maybe this approach?

```
In[180]:= x = 2; If[x < 1,
 {
  y = 2 x;
  z = 2 y
  },
 {
  y = x/2;
  z = y/2
  }
 ]


Out[180]= {1/2}
```

Comment: `If[x < 1, y = 2 x; z = 2 y, y = x/2; z = y/2]` ???

Comment: Yes, note the difference here between commas and semicolons.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. It does work. See my edits to the my original post. What I am really thinking about is if such and such is true, then I am going to write a number of steps. My approach above does do some nice indentation and makes things easier to read and understand, but is it the best approach?

Comment: The indentation is fine; the braces, not so much.

Comment: You should look up [CompoundExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) in the docs, and the tutorial linked from that page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems this question is now purely about style and will probably be closed.  However I think you may be looking for this:

```
If[x < 1,
 (
  y = 2 x;
  z = 2 y
 ),
 (
  y = x/2;
  z = y/2
 )
]
```

Though I would prefer (hat tip to WReach's comma placement):

```
If[x < 1,

  y = 2 x;
  z = 2 y

, y = x/2;
  z = y/2

]
```

If your code is very long I suggest you modularize it, i.e.:

```
doIfTrue[] := (
  y = 2 x;
  z = 2 y
)

doIfFalse[] := (
  y = x/2;
  z = y/2
)

If[x < 1, doIfTrue[], doIfFalse[]]
```

Or a more functional equivalent:

```
doIf[] /; x < 1 := (
  y = 2 x;
  z = 2 y
)

doIf[] /; ! x < 1 := (
  y = x/2;
  z = y/2
)

doIf[]
```

Comment: @MrWizard. Many helpful examples here. Thanks for your help.